# How to change CustomCell when it ends display?

Tags: swift, custom-cell, uitableview

I want to change this code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

like that:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: CustomCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

but I receive an error message. 
I need to change my CustomCell when it disappears. How can I handle this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the original method signature, and use optional casting to access `CustomCell`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = cell as? CustomCell {
        // do something with cell
    }
}
```